# Show that f(x) = 2a + 3b is continuous where a and b are constants

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Need help with a question in my book. How do I prove this is continuous.
question - 
Show that f(x) = 2a + 3b is continuous where a and b are constants

Comment: Every constant function is continuous.

Comment: i know but it is asking me to prove it.

Comment: what is the definition of continuous that you are familiar with, where are you stuck in verifying it?

Comment: First: if you have $f(x)=2a+3b$ you can say just $f(x)=k$. Second: do you mean by the Epsilon-Delta definition? Or by $\lim_{h\to0}|f(x)-f(x+h)|=0$? Or maybe other definition?

Comment: limh→0|f(x)−f(x+h)|=0limh→0|f(x)−f(x+h)|=0 is the one we have in our syllabus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition you learned is Definition in terms of limits of functions:

If $f(x)=2a+3b=k$ we have $\lim_{h\to0}|f(x)-f(x+h)|=\lim_{h\to0}|k-k|=\lim_{h\to0}0=0$ and done

Answer (score 0):

$f(x+h)=f (x)=2a+3b $.  Thus  $lim_{h\to 0}\lvert f (x+h)-f (x)\rvert =lim_{h\to 0}\lvert 2a+3b-(2a+3b)\rvert =lim_{h\to 0} \lvert 0 \rvert =0$.